# pyinstaller - No module named 'Backtrader'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I do have

```
import backtrader as bt
```

in my seal_1.py file
but still getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backtrader'
```

I thought it was the hidden import so I did

```
pyinstaller -F G:\python\Crypto_Backtesting\Seal\sealed_1.py --hidden-import backtrader
```

or

```
pyinstaller -F G:\python\Crypto_Backtesting\Seal\sealed_1.py --hidden-import='backtrader'
```

nothing worked....need help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it through terminal.

```
pip install backtrader
```

If this throws an error then try visiting the official documentation page for this library [here](https://pypi.org/project/backtrader/).